# Erro ao apurar diferença de horário com Datetime após às 00:00

Tags: php, variáveis, datetime

Estou com um problema pra apurar o tempo entre dois horários com o `datetime` quando o horário de saída fica entre a meia noite e a uma da manhã.

Por exemplo, se o primeiro horário é 14:00, e o segundo é 23:00, ele retorna certo:

> 9 horas

Mas se o segundo horário é 00:00, ele retorna:

> 14 horas

Quando deveria retornar 10 horas.

Se coloco o segundo horário em 01:00, ele ainda retorna errado:

> 13 horas

Mas se coloco 02:00, então ele já retorna certo de novo:

> 12 horas

O HTML:

```
 <label for="Cseg5">Entrada:</label>
 <input type="time" id="Cseg5" name="Tsegsss">
 <label for="Cseg6">Saída:</label>
 <input type="time" id="Cseg6" name="Tsegssss">
```

O PHP:

```
$val1 = $_POST ["hora1"];
$val2 = $_POST ["hora2"];

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);

$intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Pra transformar a propriedade em variável:

```
$horario1 = $intervalo->h;
```

Segue o `var_dump` de $val1, $val2, $horario1 e $intervalo, com os campos preenchidos com 14:00 e 00:00.

> string(5) "14:00"
>
> string(5) "00:00"
>
> int(14)
>
> object(DateInterval)#30 (15) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=>
>   int(0) 
>   **["h"]=> int(14)** ["i"]=> int(0) ["s"]=> int(0) ["weekday"]=> int(0)  ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0) ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0)
>   ["invert"]=> int(1) ["days"]=> int(0) ["special_type"]=> int(0)
>   ["special_amount"]=> int(0) ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0)
>   ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0) }

Pelo que entendi ele está subtraindo ao contrário quando passa da meia noite (até a 01 hora). Já tentei inverter as variáveis...

```
 $intervalo = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
```

Mas não resolveu. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Qual a versão do php está usando? pode ver isso criando um arquivo com o seguinte conteudo `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7

Comment: Fiz uns teste aqui obtive o resultado esperado `10  horas`, o que fiz de diferente foi passar um data completa no lugar de apenas uma hora. [Teste - exemplo](http://ideone.com/t2z6n3)

Comment: Então, mas eu quero não ter que passar a data. São vários campos `<input type="time">` apenas com HH:MM, e preciso calcular a diferença de horas e minutos entre eles... Será que com o datetime não vai ter como? Não tem alguma forma de "enganar" isso? Fazer com que sempre que passe das 23:59 ele considere como outro dia? Valeu por enquanto!

Comment: Pra ilustrar melhor editei a pergunta e coloquei o HTML. É um horário de trabalho, que pode se estender até após as 00:00, então não faz diferença a data, só o horário. Parece que ele só funciona direito se informar a data... Tem como informar uma data qualquer, só pra ele fazer a contagem da hora direito, já que to enviando a hora por formulário?

Comment: Então se vc não informa a data como ele vai saber que `$val1` é menor que `$val2` o retornaria uma valor negativo.

Comment: Então, eu queria "forçar" isso, informar de alguma maneira que val2 é sempre maior que $val1...

Comment: ehehuehu consegui(MOS)! $datetime1 = new DateTime("2015-04-05, $val1"); e $datetime2 = new DateTime("2015-05-06, $val2"); É meio que uma gambiarra né? :) Deixa eu testar de novo haha

Comment: É isso mesmo, e foi vc que me deu a letra, valeu mesmo! De novo! E foi antes da 01:00!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problema

Para calcular o intervalo de horas da maneira esperada é necessario informar a data e hora assim o objeto datetime sabe se são do mesmo dia ou de dias diferentes.

No seu exemplo se executar um `print_r` em `$datetime1` e `$datetime2` apenas com o horario será impresso algo como:

$datetime1:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-18 14:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

$datetime2

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-04-18 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

## Solução

Quando o calculo da diferença das datas/horas retorna negativo `invert` do objeto `DateInterval` retorna 1, nesse caso basta adicinoar um dia em `$datetime2` e calcular novamente a diferença.

```
function calcularIntervaloHoras($horaInicio, $horaFim){
    $intervalo = $horaInicio->diff($horaFim);

    if($intervalo->invert == 1){
       $horaFim->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
       $intervalo = $horaInicio->diff($horaFim);   
    }

    return $intervalo;

}
```

[phpfiddle - exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fkvz-9294)

Comment: Muito bom! Valeu mais uma vez!